# Dont move hint upward till keyboard appears - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml

I am using android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout in my regsister.xml
. But when page opens first edittext hint is going upward but not keyboard appears.what i want is hint go upward only when we click inside the edittext.

[image: this is image of my page when it opens.]
`

and my xml file is below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_age"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_age"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Age"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_phone_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Phone Number"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_gender"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeSpinner">

        </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_blood_group"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeSpinner">

        </Spinner>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="City"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_area"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Area"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_details"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"``
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you explicitly click on edittext, does the keyboard appear ? Did you apply android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in manifest?

Comment: yes..keyboard appears when i explicitly click on edit text.and i didnt apply android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" this one.

Comment: Check my answer pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your parent Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Hope this helps.